# CakePHP model->find and IF condition in field

Tags: php, cakephp, models

I need to construct a cakePHP model query like this:

```
SELECT `Translate`.`var_name` , IF( prove_cn_sim =1, lang_cn_sim, lang_en )
FROM 'translate` AS `Translate`
```

I've tried:

```
$this->find("list", array(
            'fields' => array("var_name","IF(prove_cn_sim = 1, lang_cn_sim, lang_en)"),
        ));
```

but I got something like this:

```
SELECT `Translate`.`var_name`, Translate.IF(prove_cn_sim = 1, lang_cn_sim, lang_en) FROM `translate` AS `Translate`
```

CakePHP add table prefix to IF. do you know any solutions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding a [virtual field](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/virtual-fields.html) to your Translate model:

```
public $virtualFields = array(
    'lang' => 'IF(Translate.prove_cn_sim = 1, Translate.lang_cn_sim, Translate.lang_en)'
);
```

Then you can always read the correct value from the virtual `lang` field when using finds on the model. Which would in your case become something like:

```
$this->find('list', array(
    'fields' => array('var_name', 'lang'),
));
```