# Cakephp sum() with multiplication

Tags: if-statement, foreach, cakephp-2.0, ternary-operator

Is it possible to find the cakephp with additional condition or can we multiply the sum() field with conditional variable?
I don't know, what could be a best question to let you guys know what I'm asking. so I'm giving a more detail about question. I'm able to find similar data with single array with some trick. but I'm unable to find for this. Please help me or give me an idea to do such task. Thanks.

Using CakePhp 2.6

I want to find data from first table here..

```
$incentiveweekly=$this->Incentive->find('all',
            array('conditions' => 
                array( 
                    "AND"=>array(
                        "Incentive.fromdate >=" => $from,
                        "Incentive.todate <=" => $to
                    )
                )
            )
    );

    according to number of rows. I have to find another table
Here is the result of above find condition.
                Array
            (
                [Incentive] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 2
                        [target1] => 3000
                        [price1] => 1.5
                        [target2] => 6000
                        [price2] => 2.5
                        [target3] => 8000
                        [price3] => 3.5
                        [formonth] => 
                        [type] => 1
                        [fromdate] => 2016-11-13
                        [todate] => 2016-11-21
                        [updatedby] => 1
                        [created] => 2016-11-15 23:57:21
                        [modified] => 2016-11-15 23:57:21
                    )

            )
            Array
            (
                [Incentive] => Array
                    (
                        [id] => 3
                        [target1] => 3000
                        [price1] => 1.5
                        [target2] => 6000
                        [price2] => 2.5
                        [target3] => 8000
                        [price3] => 3.5
                        [formonth] => 
                        [type] => 1
                        [fromdate] => 2016-11-24
                        [todate] => 2016-11-28
                        [updatedby] => 1
                        [created] => 2016-11-15 23:57:21
                        [modified] => 2016-11-15 23:57:21
                    )

            )
```

Now I want to find the array according to number of array record.

```
    $byweek=array();    // Storing Customer data by Target dates in array()             
    foreach ($incentiveweekly as $weekly){ 
        print_r($weekly);
        $target3=$weekly['Incentive']['target3'];
        $target2=$weekly['Incentive']['target2'];
        $target1=$weekly['Incentive']['target1'];
        $price3=$weekly['Incentive']['price3'];
        $price2=$weekly['Incentive']['price2'];
        $price1=$weekly['Incentive']['price1'];
        $byweek[]=$customers=$this->Customer->find('all',array(
            'fields'=>array(
            'SUM(amount) AS amount',
            'created_by'
            ),
            'group' => 'Customer.created_by',
            'conditions' => array(
                            "AND" =>array(
                                "Customer.created >=" => $weekly['Incentive']['fromdate'], 
                                "Customer.created <=" => $weekly['Incentive']['todate']
                                )
                            ),
            'recursive'=>-1     )
                    );
        //print_r($byweek);
        }
```

I'm getting result like ...

```
            Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [Customer] => Array
                                    (
                                        [created_by] => 3
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )
            Array
            (
                [0] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [Customer] => Array
                                    (
                                        [created_by] => 3
                                    )

                            )

                    )

                [1] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Array
                            (
                                [Customer] => Array
                                    (
                                        [created_by] => 1
                                    )

                            )

                        [1] => Array
                            (
                                [Customer] => Array
                                    (
                                        [created_by] => 2
                                    )

                            )

                    )

            )
```

But I want that amount would multiply with on the if else condition where I'm using ternary operator.

```
    $value[0]['amount']>=$valuem['Incentive']['target3']?"Target Third":($value[0]['amount']>=$valuem['Incentive']['target2']?"Target Second":($value[0]['amount']>=$valuem['Incentive']['target1']?"Target First":"None"))
```

Main purpose to find the details are. I want to create an incentive amount where total sales amount should be match with given target amount. If target1 amount one match then incentive would be total amount*price1 and same with target2 and target3. where i'm using tenantry operator. Target price should be multiply(by condition) with the same find condition data.

I search on google and stack overflow but can't find it's solutions. However I'm thankful to stack overflow and all you gusy that i'm able to find a lots of trick and solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks [Oldskool](https://stackoverflow.com/users/214577/oldskool) for this solution [Virtualfields with If Condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15070166/cakephp-model-find-and-if-condition-in-field)

Finaly I, Got my solutions by this code bellow. I'm getting result as expected. :)

```
            $this->Customer->virtualFields=array(
                  'incentive' => "if(SUM(Customer.amount)>=$target3,(SUM(Customer.amount))*$price3,if(SUM(Customer.amount)>=$target2,(SUM(Customer.amount))*$price2,if(SUM(Customer.amount)>=$target1,(SUM(Customer.amount))*$price1,0)))",
            );
```

Now I can use Virtualfied to get the Incentive value.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't got exactly though you can try with below solution as per my thought,

You need to use WHEN close in MYSQL,

```
$incenve = 'CASE WHEN amount>5000 THEN "FIRST Target" WHEN amount>3000 THEN "Second Target" ELSE 0 '
```

and inside fields in above query

```
'incentive' => $incentive
```

Comment: Actually I want to multiply the total amount with incentive amount. But incentive amount depends on the total amount like if (sum of total amount >= target3 amount then incentive amount would be price3) but if (sum of total amount >= target2 amount then incentive amount would be price2).

Comment: I think you are almost close to my solutions. But I want to know where do I put your suggestion code. Inside search query or out side of the search query. If I'm putting it outside of the search query. It can't find sum amount.